# Asp.net Core localization with json files

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, localization

I'm trying to find a good tutorial about asp.net localization.
In the official documentation, the explanation are about **.resx** files and I want to use json files.

If someone have a good tutorial on how to write the middleware to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Nuget Package**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Askmethat.Aspnet.JsonLocalizer/

**Solution**

After some investigations, I finally find an example in Asp/Localization GitHub.

I provide here for people that want to use a flat JSON without breaking default culture provider.

**Data :**

**The flat JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "Key": "Hello",
    "LocalizedValue" : {
      "fr-FR": "Bonjour",
      "en-US": "Hello"
    }
  }
]
```

**The C# model:**

```
class JsonLocalization
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> LocalizedValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

**The Middleware**

**The Factory**

*This is just to have access to the CultureInfo is the StringLocalizer.*

```
 public class JsonStringLocalizerFactory : IStringLocalizerFactory
 {
    public IStringLocalizer Create(Type resourceSource)
    {
        return new JsonStringLocalizer();
    }

    public IStringLocalizer Create(string baseName, string location)
    {
        return new JsonStringLocalizer();
    }
 }
```

**The Localizer**

*The logic to get the data from the JSON file*

```
public class JsonStringLocalizer : IStringLocalizer
{
    List<JsonLocalization> localization = new List<JsonLocalization>();

    public JsonStringLocalizer()
    {
        //read all json file
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        localization = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonLocalization>>(File.ReadAllText(@"localization.json"));
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            var value = GetString(name);
            return new LocalizedString(name, value ?? name, resourceNotFound: value == null);
        }
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            var format = GetString(name);
            var value = string.Format(format ?? name, arguments);
            return new LocalizedString(name, value, resourceNotFound: format == null);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetAllStrings(bool includeParentCultures)
    {
        return localization.Where(l => l.LocalizedValue.Keys.Any(lv => lv == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)).Select(l => new LocalizedString(l.Key, l.LocalizedValue[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name], true));
    }

    public IStringLocalizer WithCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new JsonStringLocalizer();
    }

    private string GetString(string name)
    {
        var query = localization.Where(l => l.LocalizedValue.Keys.Any(lv => lv == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name));
        var value = query.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Key == name);
        return value.LocalizedValue[CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name];
    }
}
```

With this solution you are able to use the basic **IStringLocalizer** in your **Views** and **Controllers**.

Of course if you have a big json file, you can use **IMemoryCache** or **IDistributedMemoryCache** to improve performance.

**EDIT :**

In the application Startup add this lines to use your own implementation :

```
services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, JsonStringLocalizerFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizer, JsonStringLocalizer>();
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

After that you can configure as you want your globalization preferences.

Comment: Can you please specify - how impement this middleware in Startup?

Comment: @Jenan I just edit my post to add Startup configuration

Comment: Great, you give great point - I get perfect result from git respositories for "JsonStringLocalizerFactory" and etc. Good job.

Comment: Good solution, but it's reasonable to split resourses in many language files, e.t.c cart.json, messages.json, products.json

Comment: Can be an evolution. The idea is to create a big blob of traductions :)

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков, I update my package to take account of your comment. Now you can have multiple ressource files under a folder :)

Comment: Each localization culture has a more generic parent culture and the root culture is invariant. If the corresponding current culture key cannot be found in the LocalizedValue keys then I would recommend that you recursively search for the first parent culture that is available.


For example. en is the parent culture of en-US and should be used in its place if en-US is unavailable.

Comment: @JamiePearcey this feature is in progress in the nuget package. An issue is open on github an the next step it to use only one localizer for multiple platform ( Xamarin, Web, Console ) with the parent culture fallback :)

Comment: @Orcuz Great! Thanks for the information. This is an excellent project btw.

Comment: I tried using this package, it does work on a basic level but it does not implement everything correctly and is therefore very buggy and behaves in unexpected ways. I don't recommend using it though there does not seem to be a better solution.

Comment: @Shikyo If you have any issue with the package, would be better to create a package a bug in the repo to help other users ? Instead of bashing it...

Comment: This design allows duplicate Key, so I am using a nested dictionary design instead.         public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> LocalizedValue = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

Comment: @StephenBuck is totally true, In the last update of the nuget package, all was moved to Dictionary :)

Comment: @OrcusZ lets say i get my "userCountry" from another API call, would the call for that user's "Title" value look like this: var titleStr = new JsonStringLocalizer().WithCulture(new CultureInfo(userCountry)).GetString("Title");?

Comment: If the call is from the controller or whatever c# code, you should be able to use the IStringLocalizer from DI. The code is just an extension of localization provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Hi can anyone tell me how to set CultureInfo using this library

Comment: @NoymulIslamChowdhury you should use options.SupportedCultureInfos to set a list of available cultures. After that, the library use the same mechanism as asp.net core localisation

Comment: Hi All , Can Anyone tell me how can I localize data annotation text using this library? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This library is using all asp.net core localisation helpers. So you just need to add the dataannotation and activate it in startup

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at here, i didnt try it myself but it looks promising.

http://ronaldwildenberg.com/asp-net-core-localization-with-json-resource-files/

Comment: The link is dead