# ASP.NET Core localization from unique JSON resource

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, localization

I am working on an ASP.NET Core (.NETCoreApp 1.1) web application with several views (including partial shared ones) and controllers that requires localization.

The constraint is that the localization strings are inside a single JSON file that has the following structure (can be changed as long as it remains in one single file):

```
{
  "HELLO": {
    "en": "Hello!",
    "fr": "Bonjour !"
  }
}
```

So I guess what I need is the localization to access this unique file and provide `IStringLocalizer` and `IViewLocalizer` objects that I can use in my controllers and views like `_localizer["HELLO"]`, obviously it is not the default pattern.

To add difficulty to this, I also need to be able to automatically detect the preferred language from the browser by default or explicitly take a language as a route value, for instance /en/Home/Index or /fr/Home/Index but also /Home/Index.

I am very new to ASP.NET Core and even with the documentation and various example achieving bits or what I need I haven't been able to implement anything reliable that I can use in production. Everything I came across has either something missing or is somehow outdated.

I would be grateful if someone who understand those things could show me how to do this!

Edit: I think I have figured out how to get the language from the route or from the browser if nothing in route. Here is what I did:

My route template is `template: "{lang?}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")` and here is the code I use to get the lang from a controller:

```
string lang = this.RouteData.Values["lang"] as string;
if (lang == null)
{
    string userLangs = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
    lang = userLangs.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With regards to using a Json file, I took this code [here](https://github.com/rwwilden/AspNet5Localization/tree/develop) and then modified it to use a single file. In the LocalizerUtil class, the ExpandPathIterator I just return "Resources\Localisation"; Its very crude but it means that I can have a single json file for each language. It doesn't do the nested languages within one file but I'm sure you could further modify it to do that too.

We went the route of storing the language choice in a cookie and allowing the user to swap languages with a dropdown.

Startup.cs

```
// Add localization
services.AddJsonLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

// Add framework services.
services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
```

And then using a combination of [this](http://www.hishambinateya.com/build-customizable-language-switcher-tag-helper-with-bootstrap) and [this](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/) blog post to get the language switcher working. If you want to use a url scheme the blog posts touch on that too.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I was afraid of... I have struggled with it for the last two days without being able to achieve what I need. I will try again tomorrow, maybe I will have some kind of epiphany.

Comment: @albator1932 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782669/909809 might be useful to get a flat file working. I was going to go the flat file route as it makes more sense having all the words next to each other so everything stays in sync but because of the lack of examples I just settled for multiple files for now.

Comment: Oh I can't believe I have missed this one, I'll give it a try right away. When I have something working I will make a complete working example to share, I can't believe how hard it is to make this.

Comment: I would love to ask for additional help about how to plug the stuff in on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615912/asp-net-core-localization-with-json-files/44782669#44782669 but I can't comment until I have 50 reputation...